# sveltekit unwanted favicon request

Tags: sveltekit

In SvelteKit App I have:

src/admin/groups

with three pages:

[id].svelte => for example: /admin/groups/1234 to load a group with id 1234

index.svelte => load a list of groups

new.svelte => create new group

by visiting /admin/groups/1234 i got an error due to favicon.png request which is not expected.

Why does it load the favicon in this page request? My config:

```
preprocess: preprocess(),

kit: {
    adapter: adapter()
},
files: {
    lib: "src/lib"
},
trailingSlash: 'always'
```

Comment: browsers will attempt to find that by default.

Comment: Yes I know, that the browser looks for favicon, but in this case my problem is caused by the following code in app.html: <link rel = "icon" href = "% sveltekit.assets% / favicon.png" />
 that forces the fetching for favicon.png in each subpath.

Answer (score 2):

In app.html changing

`<link rel="icon" href="%sveltekit.assets%/favicon.png" />`

to

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.png" />
```

solved the problem.

Comment: Where did you add this <link /> to? Did you put it in svelte:head of the app.html or in the regular <head /> element of app.html?